# Where can i find the app_id for google chromecast sender apps?

Tags: android, chromecast

Where can i find the app_id for google chromecast sender apps for sdk 3? Is it the same like the applicationId in the manifest?

Comment: TBH, I am not really sure if it's the application ID specified when you are going to [register](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration) your application. But upon seeing in [this example](https://vpaas.kaltura.com/documentation/Mobile-Video-Player-SDKs/AndroidChromeCast_V3.html), I think they are the same value.

Answer (score 0):

The `app_id` can find in `CastOptionsProvider` class like below:

```
public class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {

    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
        return new CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId("########")
            .build();
    }

    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
        return null;
    }
}
```